# Why is my rails app generating .js.js files in the application structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, coffeescript

I've got this angular/rails app going, I had been previously been playing around with vim-coffee plugins to watch my files and compile, I was using it to debug. Now, I feel like there is some residual behavior that is compiling the coffee files into .js.js files right in same folder. I'm not enjoying this behavior, though it isn't impacting the app itself. What should I be doing to address this? Actually, looking at this further, this is happening across all my coffee files in this application, as far as I can tell, it isn't happening in other projects.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @max, i'm not really into those changes you made.  for 1. copy changes are cool, but I'm not really sure that they enhance anything and 2. i'm not convinced this doesn't have something to do with the vim-coffee-script which was the tool I had been originally playing around with.

Comment: Using proper capital letters is important, it reflects on the quality of the SO site overall (as a professional resource that is, not a random forum). As for the removal of the "vim" tag, that was a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `vim` or `rails` in particular; it's just that the CoffeeScript compiler will only look at the file extension (`.coffee`).  Any other part of the file is preserved.  So you have `x.js.coffee` and it gets compiled to `x.js.js` because `.coffee` -> `.js`.  This could be anything like `x.foo.bar.coffee` would become `x.foo.bar.js` by nature of the compiler.

As you said this has no effect on the app itself, so I would just ignore it.  The generated files shouldn't even be tracked as part of your project.

Comment: I believe if you let the asset pipeline compile them for you, this won't happen.

Comment: @echristopherson right so I'm not used to seeing this behavior, the coffee files shouldn't be getting compiled locally like this.  so i must have done something somewhere that is causing something to compile the files, as I have numerous other rails apps going and none behave in this fashion.  thoughts ?

Comment: Oh, I missed that this was "residual behavior"; I thought you were using a plugin to compile them.

Answer (score 1):

yeah, so apparently I had put

`autocmd BufWritePost *.coffee silent make!`

into my ~/.vimrc and that was autocompiling coffee files, all I had to do was comment it out.  so not really a vim issue, more of a user settings configuration question but thank you all for the input and effort.